A cross-platform C library for parsing command-line arguments
I'm looking for a command-line argument parsing C library, with...
Required features:

Cross-platform (at least Linux, Windows, Mac)
Gratis
Libre
Maintained
Relatively high-level (i.e. I don't have to write my own loop going over arguments)
Featureful, e.g.:

Generates usage info
Can leaves out unparsed options for further use after parsing what it knows about
Supports both positional and non-positional parameters
Supports both --foo=bar and --foo bar
Support parameters appearing multiple times, with overriding and with aggregations into sequenced
Supports parameter name aliases, including both a single-letter and long-form aliases for the same parameter



Desired feautres:

Support for subcommands
Not based on heavy use of macro


Darren Mulholland's Args library
Website | GitHub repository

[ ] Cross-platform: Seems to assume a Unix'ish environment
[V] Gratis
[V] Libre: 0BSD license
[V] Maintained: Last commit is from 3 weeks ago
[V] Relatively high-level
Features:

[?] Generates usage info: Not clear from the docs
[?] Can leave out unparsed options for further use after parsing what it knows about
[V] Supports both positional and non-positional parameters
[?] Supports both --foo=bar and --foo bar
[V] Support parameters appearing multiple times, with overriding and with aggregations into sequenced
[X] Supports parameter name aliases, including both a single-letter and long-form aliases for the same parameter


[V] Support for subcommands
[V] Not based on heavy use of macros


Yecheng Fu's argparse
(No Website) | GitHub repository

[ ] Cross-platform: Seems to assume a Unix'ish environment
[V] Gratis
[V] Libre: MIT license
[V] Maintained: Last commit is from 4 months ago
[V] Relatively high-level
Features:

[V] Generates usage info: Not clear from the docs
[?] Can leave out unparsed options for further use after parsing what it knows about
[V] Supports both positional and non-positional parameters
[?] Supports both --foo=bar and --foo bar
[?] Support parameters appearing multiple times, with overriding and with aggregations into sequenced
[?] Supports parameter name aliases, including both a single-letter and long-form aliases for the same parameter


[V] Support for subcommands
[ ] Not based on heavy use of macros

